# foldLeft on List of Tuples: strange unexpected results

Tags: scala, foldleft

I am having a list of tuples which elements I want to be summed:

```
val t = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).map(el => (el,1))
t: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1))

t.foldLeft(0,0){ case ((a,b),(c,d)) => (a+b,c+d)}
res3: (Int, Int) = (14,6)
```

The answer `(14,6)` is unexpected indeed (expected one was `(15,5)`).

What puzzles me even more:

```
t.foldLeft(0,1){ case ((a,b),(c,d)) => (a+b,c+d)}
res3: (Int, Int) = (15,6)
```

My questions are what do parameters in `foldLeft(x,y)` correspond to (are they initiation params for 1st and 2nd folds???) and how to get the desired sums over 1st and 2nd elements of tuple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an error in your folding function. Your accumulator is in (a,b) and element is in (c,d). In order to sum you should return (a+c, b+d)

Comment: For debug just replace fold by scan.